# Webservice returns 404 (Not Found)

Tags: .net, web-services, c#-4.0

Hi all I am building a webservice. The service has been built on my localhost so when I hit the URL in browser, for example, http://127.0.0.1/api/MyTest/GetStatus would actually respond with expected message.

```
<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>
```

However it returns a 404 not found when I try to hit that with a script file. Message returns as `"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://127.0.0.1/api/MyTest/GetStatus'."`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/api/MyTest/GetStatus',   
    type: 'POST',    
    contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-16',   
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
</script>
```

The same script I have been using on other services and they are all responding correctly. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make a few assumptions seeing that you didn't provide us with your ServerSide Code.

I'm assuming you are using WebApi and that your controller method looks similar to this:

```
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, ActionName("GetStatus")]
    public void GetStatus(string value)
    {

    }
 }
```

This would explain why you are getting

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

when you make the request through the browser.

The reason why you are getting 404 not found on your POST is probably because you are not POSTING any data along with the request but your Controller Method is expected some value.

Either try changing your AJAX call to include POST data :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/api/MyTest/GetStatus',   
    type: 'POST',    
    data: {someData}
    contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-16',   
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Ensuring that your POST data format matches your Controller method signature.

OR

You called your Controller method "GetStatus", so I'm assuming you're trying to get some status back from your server.

Is there really a need for a POST? Did you perhaps mean to use GET instead?

If so, you should change your Method signature to:

```
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, ActionName("GetStatus")]
    public string GetStatus()
    {
        return "SomeStatus";
    }
}
```

And update your AJAX call to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/api/MyTest/GetStatus',   
    type: 'GET',    
    contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-16',   
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's very close to the root cause - method signature. Appreciated.

Comment: No problem, most of these 404 problems are usually either your method signature or Routing problem.