# Fiddler post request to .net mvc controller returns 404

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, http, fiddler

I have controller which is

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserRights(int id)
    {
        var rights = _rightsService.GetUserRights(id);
        if (rights == null)
        {
            return new HttpActionResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "User not found");
        }
        return Ok(rights);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SetUserRights(int id, IEnumerable<EditRightViewModel> rights)
    {
        Result result = _rightsService.SetUserRights(id, rights);
        if (!result.IsSuccess)
        {
            return new HttpActionResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, result.Message);
        }
        return Ok(result.Data);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SetUserRights(int id, int RightId, bool Enable)
    {
        Result result = _rightsService.SetUserRights(id, new List<EditRightViewModel>
        {
            new EditRightViewModel
            {
                RightId = RightId,
                Enable = Enable
            }
        });
        if (!result.IsSuccess)
        {
            return new HttpActionResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, result.Message);
        }
        return Ok(result.Data);
    }
```

The get request works fine but the post returns 404.
The request is

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:577
Content-Length: 44
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
"id":1,
"RightId":1,
"Enable":"true"
}
```

Originally I want to send data to the post action that has a list as parameter. I thought that reason why it returns 404 is that json doesn't fits the function's arguments. So I simplified json and action parameters but it still won't work. Maybe someone can tell what's the reason of the problem and how to write a correct json to send list as a parameter?

Comment: What is the post request url?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the request?

Comment: the url is /api/rights/SetUserRights
Managed to send request by making this signature 
IHttpActionResult SetUserRights(int id, EditRightViewModel editModel)
and sending id as parameter in url /api/rights/SetUserRights/1

Simple parameters can't be part of the JSON. They must go to the url parameters

Answer (score 0):

404 Errors mostly occur when you Method signature does not match your `POST` data or when your Routing is not configured correctly.

Have a look at my answer here - [Webservice return 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272596/webservice-returns-404-not-found/33274986#33274986)

I would change the Method signature to accept a class instead.

```
public class UserRights
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int RightId {get;set;}
    public bool Enable {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post Actions can not have most one argument in body.
Create a class with the parameters you need. ASP NET will do the binding.

```
public IHttpActionResult SetUserRights(Right right){ /* ... */ }

public class Right {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int RightId { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Ok But imagine that I also have list of objects in this model. Then what json should be composed to this this method? `{
"UserId":1,
"RightsToSet":
 [
  { 
    "RightId":1,
    "Enable":true,
  }
  { 
    "RightId":2,
    "Enable":true,
  }
  { 
    "RightId":3,
    "Enable":true,
  }
 ]
}` This doesn't work :(
Model variable in the method is null

Comment: You can have a property `IEnumerable<>`, no problem. You have a problem in this JSON. Objects of list `RightsToSet` must be separated by `,`: `"RightsToSet": [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ]`.